# How can i change gender in Dasha.ai?

Tags: dasha

I have written node.js code in which I used Dasha's SDK but I can't change Dasha's voice on Dasha.ai, how can I change the voice from a female to a male?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today Dasha doesn't support Male voices. But you can use [Custom TTS](https://docs.dasha.ai/en-us/default/tutorials/custom-tts/) and use any other Text To Speech provider.